# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression when trying to export to csv file

Tags: powershell

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to export to a CSV file:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Orion\scripts\start.ps1:219 char:5
+     $DeviceInfo =[PSCustomObject]@{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Export-CSV : The file 'C:\temp\device_information.csv' already exists.
At C:\Orion\scripts\start.ps1:226 char:19
+ ... eviceInfo | Export-CSV C:\temp\device_information.csv -NoClobber -NoT ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\temp\device_information.csv:String) [Export-Csv], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoClobber,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

This is what I currently have:

device_information.psm1:

```
class DeviceInformation {
    [string]$DeviceName;
    [string]$DeviceManufacturer;
    [string]$DeviceModel;
    [string]$DeviceSerialNumber;
    [string]$DevicePhysicalMACAddress;
    [string]$DeviceDomainName;
    [string]$DeviceIPAddress;

    DeviceInformation() {
        $this.DeviceName                    = $env:COMPUTERNAME;
        $this.DeviceManufacturer            = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Manufacturer -ExpandProperty Manufacturer;
        $this.DeviceModel                   = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Model -ExpandProperty Model;
        $this.DeviceSerialNumber            = Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS | Select-Object SerialNumber -ExpandProperty SerialNumber;
        $this.DevicePhysicalMACAddress      = (Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $this.DeviceName | Where-Object{$_.IpEnabled -Match "True"} | Select-Object -Expand MacAddress) -join ", ";
        $this.DeviceDomainName              = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domain;
        $this.DeviceIPAddress               = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet).IPAddress;
    }

    [string]GetDeviceName() {
        return $this.DeviceName;
    }

    [string]GetDeviceManufacturer() {
        return $this.DeviceManufacturer;
    }

    [string]GetDeviceModel() {
        return $this.DeviceModel;
    }

    [string]GetDeviceSerialNumber() {
        return $this.DeviceSerialNumber;
    }

    [string]GetDevicePhysicalMACAddress() {
        return $this.DevicePhysicalMACAddress;
    }

    [string]GetDeviceDomainName() {
        return $this.DeviceDomainName;
    }

    [string]GetDeviceIPAddress() {
        return $this.DeviceIPAddress;
    }
}
```

start.ps1:

```
function OnExportDeviceInformationClick($DeviceInformation) {
    $DeviceInfo =[PSCustomObject]@{
        'DeviceName' = $DeviceInformation.GetDeviceManufacturer();
        'DeviceManufacturer' = $DeviceInformation.GetDeviceManufacturer();
        'DeviceModel' = $DeviceInformation.GetDeviceModel();
        'DeviceSerialNumber' = $DeviceInformation.GetDeviceSerialNumber();
    }

    $DeviceInfo | Export-CSV C:\temp\device_information.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I'm new to powershell and not sure what to do with this, the examples I've seen don't actually initialise the variable before exporting it. It's probably something very simple and easy but I just don't know where to start with it.

Comment: `[object]` does not have such methods, seems like you forgot to create a new instance of your class...

Comment: Looks like you forgot to pass an argument for `-DeviceInformation` when you invoke `OnExportDeviceInformationClick`. Please show us the part of the code/script where you actually call `OnExportDeviceInformationClick`